# Can this JSON with "timestamp" : Double format be aggregated for SUM, AVG in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, formatting

I have imported the above json data into it's own collection on mongoDB database. I'm trying to aggregate the values (ie 40, 30, 30) and SUM and AVG them as they reside in the inner most embedded document. I'm having a problem doing this when I try using dot notation and can not get any vaules.  I feel the unique timestamps  (ie 1567544426000, 1567541464000, 1567541475000) are a problem. Is this json file formatted correctly for aggregation and how would I do so. Thanks for any help or if you can even point me in the right direction where I can find out how to do SUM, AVG etc to the data.

I've tried use NoSQLBooster and Query ASsist for MongoDB

```
{
    "Barcode": "97-1908-577-1032-BE1-332",
    "IP": "192.162.656.111",
    "VFD": {
        "CurrentPV": {
            "Type": "Speed",
            "Data": {
                "1567544426000": 40,
                "1567541464000": 30
                "1567541475000": 30
            }
        },
        "CurrentSP": {
            "Type": "Speed",
            "Data": {
                "1567544426000": 55,
                "1567541464000": 5
                "1567541488000": 10
            }
        },
        "Program_Running": {
            "Type": "Active",
            "Data": {
                "1567544426000": 1,
                "1567541464000": 0
                "1567541475000": 3
            }
        }
    },
    "Equipment": "PieceOfEquipment",
    "Location": "Garage",
    "RunEnd": "NA",
    "RunStart": 1533541438
}
```

I can't seem to reach the values even when I use dot notation down to the "Data" branch object (ie Equipment.VFD.CurrentPV.Data) but no result sets are returned.

Comment: Thanks again and any help would be greatly, greatly apprecieted!

Comment: So I've learned the JSON Keys can only be strings not numbers. Although I'm receiving a string it's really a number encased in quotes so believe these aren't valid keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the `VFD.CurrentPV.Data` into an array of key-value pairs using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and then perform **SUM** and **AVG** on the values itself.

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "data":{
                $objectToArray: "$VFD.CurrentPV.Data"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "sum":{
                $sum:"$data.v"
            },
            "avg":{
                $avg:"$data.v"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d830f3afb35a835fbd8638e"),
    "Barcode" : "97-1908-577-1032-BE1-332",
    "IP" : "192.162.656.111",
    "VFD" : {
        "CurrentPV" : {
            "Type" : "Speed",
            "Data" : {
                "1567544426000" : 40,
                "1567541464000" : 30,
                "1567541475000" : 30
            }
        },
        "CurrentSP" : {
            "Type" : "Speed",
            "Data" : {
                "1567544426000" : 55,
                "1567541464000" : 5,
                "1567541488000" : 10
            }
        },
        "Program_Running" : {
            "Type" : "Active",
            "Data" : {
                "1567544426000" : 1,
                "1567541464000" : 0,
                "1567541475000" : 3
            }
        }
    },
    "Equipment" : "PieceOfEquipment",
    "Location" : "Garage",
    "RunEnd" : "NA",
    "RunStart" : 1533541438
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d830f3afb35a835fbd8638e"),
    "sum" : 100,
    "avg" : 33.333333333333336
}
```

Comment: Hi, TY for for help. I will look into your suggestion tommorrow at work and report back. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, After installing the current version of mongodb (from version 2.x which doesn't have $addfields) to version 4.2 it worked.